# 1 file 2 pagination script

Tags: php, pagination

I have a file where I am showing two different reports. So these two different reports needs two different pagination scripts. I have done this. Pagination is working fine. But i have some issue.
1-When I clicks on 3rd page of 1st report it goes on 3rd page. But when I click on any page of second report the first report again comes to 1st page and vice versa.
I am setting different variables of limit, offset, no of records, no of pages for both scripts. 
Here is the script for first script

```
$limit1=10;
//nor is method that return total number of rows
$nor1=nor("select count(*) as num from order_details where artist_id=".$_SESSION["sess_artistid"]);
if( isset($_GET['pn1']) && $_GET['pn1']-0>0)
$pn1=$_GET['pn1'];
else
$pn1=1;
$nop1=ceil($nor1 / $limit1);
if($pn1>$nop1)
$pn1=1;
$offset1=($pn1-1) * $limit1;
```

then I query to table and shows record. and here I am showing pagination for first script

```
for($i=1;$i<=$nop1;$i++)
{
 if($i==$_GET['pn1'])
 echo('<a style="font-weight:bold;">'.$i.'</a>');
 else
 echo('<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn1='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>');
}
```

Now for second report I am using the following code snipt

```
$limit=7;
$nor=nor("select count(*) as num from order_details where product_id in(".implode(',',$products).") and artist_id in(".implode(',',$vendors).")");
if( isset($_GET['pn']) && $_GET['pn']-0>0)
$pn=$_GET['pn'];
else
$pn=1;
$nop=ceil($nor / $limit);
if($pn>$nop)
$pn=1;
$offset=($pn-1) * $limit;
```

Then again query to table to show record and here showing pagination for second report

```
for($i=1;$i<=$nop;$i++)
{
if($i==$_GET['pn'])
echo('<a style="font-weight:bold;">'.$i.'</a>');
else
echo('<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>');
}
```

As for as I am understanding, When any of the other report is clicked it sets the first report pn=1 that's why it goes to first page again. But not understanding how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `&pn=$pn` to all links that currently contain `?pn1=$pn1` and vice versa.